# Help understanding syntax used in security proof

Tags: provable-security

I am looking through [this paper](https://www.di.ens.fr/~mabdalla/papers/AbPo05a-letter.pdf) and am trying to understand the proofs better. One of the theorems the authors are proving (Theorem 5.1) contains syntax of **Adv** followed by "cdh" in the superscript and some values as parameters within parentheses after. I've posted an image of the theorem in question for convenience. What does this syntax mean and what do the parameters for it mean?

[image: Theorem from proof]

Comment: Read the paper again from the beginning; every notation is properly defined.

Comment: @fkraiem I'm not very familiar with proofs like this. Taking your advice I reread the CDH definition and saw that the parameter to ADV-CDH could represent a time complexity. Conceptually I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Probably you just don't have the necessary prerequisites to understand that paper; it's like trying to understand the operation manual for a Boeing jetliner when you have only flown a toy drone... At the risk of being scolded by moderators again, I'll advise you to first cover the basics from a good textbook, and come back to that paper later.

Comment: @fkraiem Thank you for your polite reply. I am in the uncomfortable position of needing to understand computational proofs and I was hoping I could gain some insight by examining the proof in this paper, but I agree that it is probably beyond what I could learn within a short time without a better understanding of the basics.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to understand it is to consider that the best algorithm we know to break CDH in $\mathbb{G}$ has advantage (id est: probability to win) is $\mathbf{Adv}^{\text{cdh}}_{\mathbb{G}}$.

You can suppose that this parameter is very small (exponentially small).

The goal of this theorem is to prove that if an adversary could break ake of SPAKE, $\mathcal{D}$, then this advantage (probability to win) is smaller of the right expression.

By looking the right expression, you deduce it's small (because $\mathbf{Adv}^{\text{cdh}}_\mathbb{G}$ is exponentially small)